# Symfony programmatic form validation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In Symfony 2.5.10, I have multiple form types, each with their own validation groups, calling various class constraints. Each type represents a particular step in a workflow. The final step iterates over all other steps, performs the necessary validation and displays any possible violations to the user.

The data behind each form type (data_class) is always the same: a doctrine entity.

Each displayed violation links to the URL/path representing the step in question, with an additional parameter which, when present, should trigger the validation. The idea is that the form should display the errors immediately, without submitting. In other words, I wish to trigger form submission programmatically (server-side, not JS!).

I've tried various different ways:

1. Somehow put the entity (which I have) into the request and set the method of the latter to POST, so that Form::handleRequest handles everything automatically. Problem: converting the entity object to an array, as would be returned from a real form submission. Maybe a DataTransformer? PropertyAccessor?
2. As 1. but call Form::submit instead. See http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#calling-form-submit-manually
3. Validate myself (in the same way I do in the final step), giving me a ConstraintViolationList. Iterate over the list and call Form::addError for each violation. Problem: I need to add the errors to the correct child elements, not just the parent. Maybe I could do this using the propertyPath of each error, but how to go from that to child form?

Any help would be much appreciated. I've trawled stackoverflow and the web in general, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

First way looks good. You just should check the ajax form and them just use something like

```
$entity = $form->getData()
```

to retrieve data from form (which could be array, entity, or some other stuff you have in you form).

Then just pass this entity to the twig view to form an request answer. Alongside with entity you might want to provide form errors aquired from `$form->createView()` FormView object.